# Data Source cannot be empty. Use :memory: to open an in-memory database

Tags: c#, sqlite

Я создаю программу на C# с подключенной базой данных на SQLite. При отладке выскакивает вот такая ошибка: исключение не обработано. `"Data Source cannot be empty.  Use :memory: to open an in-memory database"`.

Ниже скрин из отладчика:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь мой код.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SQLite;

namespace Diplom_BM
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private SQLiteConnection DB;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DB = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=F:\\Maxim\\1.db; Pooling=true; FailIfMissing=false; Version=3");
            DB.Open();
        }

        public string admins;
        Autentification auth;

        private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtLogin.Text != string.Empty
                  && txtPassword.Text != string.Empty)
            {
                checkAccount(txtLogin.Text, txtPassword.Text);
            }
        }

        private void checkAccount(string login, string password)
        {
            auth = new Autentification();
            auth.getConnection();

            using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(auth.connectionString))
            {
                con.Open();   //Здесь программа вылетает
                SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand();
                string query = @"SELECT FROM Admins WHERE Login='" + login + "'";

                int count = 0;
                cmd.CommandText = query;
                cmd.Connection = con;

                SQLiteDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (read.Read())
                {
                    count++;
                }

                if (count == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Вы успешно вошли в систему.", "Вход произведен.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    admins = login;
                    this.Close();
                }

                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Неверное имя пользователя или пароль.", "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    return;
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Максим, без Вашей базы анализировать Ваш код можно только визуально, без отладчика, да и не всегда бывает доступ к среде разработки. Поэтому есть смысл в тексте программы отметить строку, где было выброшено исключение. Это сэкономит время людей, которые могут Вам помочь.

Comment: Прошу прощения. Вставил скриншот с ошибкой в вопрос.

Comment: Значит, для дальнейшего анализа нужно смотреть, что из себя представляет auth.connectionString. Очень возможно, что Вам следует воспользоваться советом, который Вам дал другой участник дискуссии, хотя это маловероятно, иначе у Вас программа вылетела еще на этапе загрузки формы.

Comment: Хорошо. Что мне делать дальше?

Comment: Посмотреть в отладчике, что там в  auth.connectionString и значение добавить в вопрос. Кстати, я слегка изменил структуру Вашего вопроса. Если Вы согласны с этим, то есть смысл принять изменения, пока Вы не начали редактировать свой вопрос.

Comment: Кстати, очень хороший ресурс https://www.connectionstrings.com/ - может помочь в Вашем случае.

Comment: На скриншоте видно содержимое auth.connectionString: `"@Data.Source=1.db"` Исправляйте.

Comment: У вас зачем-то и в событии Load создаётся соединение (поле формы), и непосредственно в методе ещё одно соединение.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте

DB = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=F:\Maxim\1.db; Pooling=true; FailIfMissing=false; Version=3");

Ошибка связана с подключением к базе.